# Problema ordenamiento de números con método burbuja

Tags: c

Estoy realizando un pequeño "programa" usando el método de burbuja a modo de práctica personal pero presento errores al querer realizar el ordenamiento de forma ascendente o descendente.

Presenta dos errores, el primer error está en que uno de los números introducidos se convierte en un cero lo cual interfiere en el funcionamiento del programa y hace que no funcione correctamente, y el segundo error es que en ocasiones el `for` donde se solicitan los números a evaluar presenta problemas, es decir, no se repite la cantidad de veces que se solicita.

Este último ocurre mayormente cuando se ingresa una cantidad grande de números a solicitar, por ejemplo 10 números.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    int opcion = 0;
    int cantidad_numeros = 0;
    int numeros [cantidad_numeros];
    int auxiliar = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    printf ("\t --- Metodo Burbuja ---");
    printf ("\n 1. Ordenar numeros en forma ascendente");
    printf ("\n 2. Ordenar numeros en forma descendete");
    printf ("\n 3. Salir");
    printf ("\n \n Por favor seleccione una opcion  ");
    scanf ("%d", & opcion);
    switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            system ("cls");
            printf ("\t --- Metodo Burbuja Ascendente ---");
            printf ("\n Por favor ingrese la cantidad de numeros a digitar  ");
            scanf ("%d", & cantidad_numeros);
            for (i=0; i<cantidad_numeros; i++) {
                printf ("Ingrese el numero %d  ", i+1);
                scanf ("%d", & numeros[i]);
            }
            for (i=0; i<cantidad_numeros-1; i++) {
                for (j=0; j<cantidad_numeros; j++) {
                    if (numeros[j] > numeros[j+1]) {
                        auxiliar = numeros[j];
                        numeros[j] = numeros[j+1];
                        numeros[j+1] = auxiliar;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i=0; i<cantidad_numeros; i++) {
                printf ("%d \t", numeros[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            system ("cls");
            printf ("\t --- Metodo Burbuja Descendente ---");
            printf ("\n Por favor ingrese la cantidad de numeros a digitar  ");
            scanf ("%d", & cantidad_numeros);
            for (i=0; i<cantidad_numeros; i++) {
                printf ("Ingrese el numero %d  ", i+1);
                scanf ("%d", & numeros[i]);
            }
            for (i=0; i<cantidad_numeros-1; i++) {
                for (j=0; j<cantidad_numeros; j++) {
                    if (numeros[j] < numeros[j+1]) {
                        auxiliar = numeros[j];
                        numeros[j] = numeros[j+1];
                        numeros[j+1] = auxiliar;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i=0; i<cantidad_numeros; i++) {
                printf ("%d \t", numeros[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            printf ("Saliendo...");
            sleep (1);
            break;
        default :
            printf ("Ingrese una opcion valida");       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tienes una manera curiosa de medir las escalas, 70 líneas de código te parece un programa "pequeño" y 10 números introducidos te parece una gran cantidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El algoritmo burbuja lo tienes casi bien. La idea es comparar cada número con su siguiente e intercambiarlos en caso de que sea necesario. Para eso recorres los números del primero al penúltimo. Tus bucles deberían ser así:

```
for (i=0; i<cantidad_numeros-1; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<cantidad_numeros; j++) {
//       ^^^^^ <-- Desde el siguiente, hasta el último.
        if (numeros[j] > numeros[i]) {
//                  ^            ^ <-- Comparamos el presente con el siguiente.
            auxiliar = numeros[j];
            numeros[j] = numeros[i];
//                  ^            ^ <-- Intercambiamos el presente con el siguiente.
            numeros[i] = auxiliar;
//                  ^ <-- Siguiente se queda con el auxiliar guardado.
        }
    }
}
```

Pero el algoritmo mal redactado es el menor de tus problemas. Lo que seguramente te está provocando problemas es tu uso completamente inadecuado de las formaciones<sup>1</sup>.

En [c](/questions/tagged/c), una formación<sup>1</sup> definida en espacio de memoria automático debe tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación, en tu caso su tamaño es una variable (conocida en tiempo de ejecución) y para más inri de tamaño cero:

```
int cantidad_numeros = 0;
int numeros [cantidad_numeros];
```

Para empeorar la cosa, las variables se definen una vez, no se adaptan dinámicamente. Así que si cambias `cantidad_numeros` en el futuro, la definición del pasado no cambiará. En resumen, todo mal ahí. La manera correcta de obtener memoria dinámica es mediante `malloc`:

```
int cantidad_numeros = 0;
int *numeros = NULL;

// ... código ...

        printf ("\n Por favor ingrese la cantidad de numeros a digitar  ");
        scanf ("%d", & cantidad_numeros);
        numeros = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * cantidad_numeros);
```

Si reservas memoria con `malloc` deberás liberarla con `free`:

```
// ... código ...
free(numeros);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como arreglos, o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de total ayuda los comentarios y sugerencias